# Is there any library in javascript that is similar to JFugue in Java?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, jfugue

With JFugue, synthesizing music is as simple as this:

```
Player player = new Player();
player.play("C D E F G A B");
```

While I do realize that the HTML5 Audio API is still under development for most of the browsers, I am quite unaware if any of these browsers support an API like this.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [music.js](https://github.com/GregJ/music.js). They have a demo of it in action [here](http://code.gregjopa.com/javascript/audio/musicjs/demo/), but the code looks somewhat like what you've described:

```
var n = Note.fromLatin('A4');
```

However, I'm not sure that it actually handles the 'play' part, and it likely uses the HTML5 audio tag.

As for what browsers support the audio tag, that's an easier question: http://caniuse.com/#search=audio

Comment: It's 2016 now, (and your link is dead). Anything changed over the years?